# How to correctly export to pdf org-roam files

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, org-roam

I have three files A, B and C. A is a table of contents with links to B and C that have various information, the problem is I want to export a pdf with the content of A, B and C together but `org-latex-export-to-pdf` only export one file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can `#+INCLUDE` them all in D and export that. But the links in A will not work in the PDF file since they point to things in B and C, not to things in (the PDF version of) D. That probably is not what you want but it's not clear to me why you want to do the above: the normal export creates a TOC so why do you want another one in A?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NickD! I will give it a try.
I'm using A because is an easy way to see every category I have and don't forget them, I really struggle to remember so this is an easy way for me of knowing what knowledge I have about something

Comment: But does it have to be included in the PDF?

Comment: Not necessarily, it was just for convenience. I will try the solution you gave me