# org-roam: export to pdf: inline node links

Tags: pdf, org-roam

I am using [orgroam](https://www.orgroam.com/), because it allows me to focus on smaller steps. But, sometimes I want to export a note to pdf but inline all links to other nodes.

So lets say I have a node called `main` that contains links to nodes `sub1` and `sub2`. While working I like that `main` does not show the content of `sub1`, `sub2`. But when communicating with other people I would like to present one cohesive document. So I want to export `main` to pdf but automatically inline all the content of `sub1` and `sub2`.

What I have found so far:

- `org-latex-export-to-pdf` fails because it cannot resolve the link
- post [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68309/how-to-correctly-export-to-pdf-org-roam-files) did not help.
- [org-roam discourse](https://org-roam.discourse.group/t/export-to-pdf-but-following-links/2957/2) had a similar question, but still no answer.

Is there any easy solution here that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

[dlukes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10334/dlukes) answer in [Org-roam links are considered broken when exporting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69048/org-roam-links-are-considered-broken-when-exporting) did the trick for me:
Run

```
M-x org-roam-update-org-id-locations
```

before running your pdf export. I did not yet find any shortcomings from this.